# Trouble with Python generators in recursive implementation of minimax

Tags: python, recursion, generator, minimax

I am working on an implementation of minimax algorithm to solve 2048. I am facing problems when iterating over a list of objects, and passing this value to recursive functions. The code is :

```
def MAXIMIZE(state,deep):
if deep == 10:
    return (None,greed(state))

tup = (None, -1000000) #maxChild, maxUtility 
moves = state.getAvailableMoves()
#children by moves
children = []
children.append(state.clone().move(m) for m in moves)
for child in children:
    temp,utility = MINIMIZE(child,deep + 1)
    if utility > tup[1]:
        tup = (child, utility)

return tup
def MINIMIZE(state,deep):
if deep == 10:
    return (None, greed(state))
tup = (None, +10000000)

cells = state.getAvailableCells() # this is where I get an error - "'generator' object has no attribute 'getAvailableCells'"

children = []
children.append(state.clone().setCellValue(cell, 2) for cell in cells)
for child in children:
    temp,utility = MAXIMIZE(child,deep + 1)
    if utility < tup[1]:
        tup = (child,utility)
return tup
```

In the MINIMIZE function the line - cells = state.getAvailableCells() gives "'generator' object has no attribute 'getAvailableCells'"
Can anyone please help me figure this out? (I am a student of physics and have limited knowledge of Python. I went to various existing questions but couldn't understand much.)

Comment: Fix your indentations. This does not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
children = []
children.append(state.clone().move(m) for m in moves)
```

You create an empty `list`, then add one single element to it, this element being a generator (created by the `state.clone().move(m) for m in moves` [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)).

What you want is a list expression instead - replace those two lines with:

```
children = [state.clone().move(m) for m in moves)]
```

This will evaluate the generator and build and populate a list from it.

Note that you have the same problem here:

```
children = []
children.append(state.clone().setCellValue(cell, 2) for cell in cells)
```

which requires the same fix:

```
children = [state.clone().setCellValue(cell, 2) for cell in cells]
```